# Condition for rolling uphill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

In the follow setup a cylinder of radius R and mass M is given an initial angular velocity (while initial linear velocity is 0). Coeffs of friction (both static and kinetic) are given.
[image]

The question is under which condition will the cylinder roll uphill?

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, especially since I am not told whether the rolling is pure or not. My only idea is to simply use Newton's 2nd law to find a condition over μ while assuming the rolling is not perfect and thus f=Nμ. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Write 2nd Newton's law taking into account three forces: gravity, friction and torque. Figure out what should be the maximum value of angle $\beta$ to allow the cylinder to move upwards.

Comment: But how do I know if the friction is static or kinetic? Does it matter?

Comment: Have you drawn a free body diagram showing the forces and torques involved?

Comment: Site policy is that such questions must **show an attempt** to solve the problem and **ask about a conceptual difficulty**.

Comment: he *showed an attempt* christ. His conceptual difficulty is that he can't solve the problem using known physics concepts. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: static friction acts in the opposite direction to kinetic friction here btw

Comment: What is non-pure rolling? This situation can be considered ideal (stiff, rigid surface and wheel) meaning that there is only either rolling or not rolling. And rolling means static while not-rolling (but sliding) means kinetic friction. Your solution idea is good and should work, just forget about all the talk about non-perfect surfaces and and non-pure rolling. Unless it is rolling on a sand beach or a soft carpet or with  a soft rubber wheel, there is often only negligible rolling resistance, so you can trust it to be ideal with static friction only, when there is rolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the initial linear velocity is 0 but the cylinder is rotating, the initial motion *is not* pure rolling: the cylinder is slipping.

Examining the free body diagram, there are three forces acting on the center of mass: gravity (down), the normal force (perpendicular to the surface), and *kinetic* friction uphill.  (The friction is kinetic because the cylinder is slipping--again, $v=0$ but $\omega\ne0$.  The direction of friction is up the slope because friction always opposes motion, in this case the rotation.)

We can split the forces into components.  The component of gravity perpendicular to the surface of the incline will be exactly cancelled by the normal force.

If the friction force is larger than the gravitational weight of the cylinder along the direction parallel to the incline, then the cylinder will go uphill; otherwise, the cylinder will go downhill.